# What is the exact name of this RC nitro engine specific carburator part?

Tags: carburetor, small-engine

I've a Traxxas Pro .15 engine with me. The rubber boot attached to "Throttle lever" on my carburetor is cracked (picture given below). The engine has been in storage for the last one year. Yesterday while trying to fire it up I noticed this.

Can anyone help me with finding the specific name of this part so I purchase it individually. I tried searching Traxxas website but they seem to sell the carburetor only as a whole and that's like $40 excluding shipping.

[image]

Comment: Nothing is popping out to me as "broke" ... can you annotate what you're talking about?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I've updated the picture. Hope this helps. I was referring to the cracks on the rubber. Does this affect it's performance?